# Automating High Availability and Disaster Recovery Tests

Tags: testing, automated-tests, high-availability, disaster-recovery

Can anyone suggest some good test automation strategies or design patterns for high availability and disaster recovery testing?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to avoid failure is to fail constantly. Netflix uses a strategy called "Chaos Monkey", the code can be found here: [SimianArmy](https://github.com/Netflix/SimianArmy). It generated random failures in your cloud infrastructure making you prepared to any random disaster.